# Select Parent checkbox based on child checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to select a parent checkbox when child checkbox is selected. But The the problem is that my code selects all the parents checkboxes. And I don't have selected property with each category. I need to use the index somehow to target the exact parent category
Hers is my code.

```
 <ul class="categories">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index">
                <li>
                  <input
                    formControlName="parentCat"
                    [checked]="parent"
                    type="checkbox"
                    [value]="cat.name"
                  />
                  {{ cat.name }}
                  <ng-container
                    *ngFor="let sub of cat.sub_categories; let k = index"
                  >
                    <li *ngIf="cat.sub_categories">
                      <input
                        formControlname="childCat"
                        (change)="categoryChange($event, cat)"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value="sub.name"
                      />{{ sub.name }}
                    </li>
                  </ng-container>
                </li>
              </ng-container>
            </ul>
```

Now here is my function

```
parent: boolean;
categoryChange(event) {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.parent = true;
    } else {
      this.parent = false;
    }
  }
```

Each child category should select related parent category.

Answer (score -1):

Here, Parent is global one you need to set selected per category.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txhnxj